# Bogus rejection reason for an edit by the post's author

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I've been doing some edits lately and am now getting a warning when editing because of some rejected edits. While I can agree with the most of the rejections, one rejection is bogus in my eyes.

The post in question is this one: [Python code to search Google returns an empty list of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110642/not-getting-output-in-python-code-for-finding-anything-on-google)

The author rejected my edits with

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the edit review]

I don't think my edit is promoting any services, nor is it destructive to the posts content. The author has since made a similar edit to mine.

Is this rejection warranted? If so, why? I'd really like to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I see no reason why the edit should be rejected.

Comment: I think that's one of the pre-written reject-reasons and seeing as the OP (or his account at least) is brand new I'd put it down to them just being unfamiliar with the UI. This is of course just me guessing since I can't read their mind.

Comment: I think assuming good faith is the best course of action here. The user is likely unfamiliar with the UI and also unaccustomed to having edits made to their post by other people. I wouldn't take this too harsh if I were you. Do note that you made a small typo `emtpy` should be `empty`. It's even possible that's why the user rejected. Slim chance but possible - I've seen people reject edits by accident when they just wanted to address a small thing in the edit.

Comment: To catch errors like *"emtpy"*, install and/or enable spellchecking in the browser (though unnecessary convoluted in the case of Firefox). In Firefox, to update after a change to the text, switch to another tab and back (I consider this to be a bug). Beware of US vs. British English differences (I "train" the spellchecker to accept both). I also have [a wordlist](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) (but it should *never* be applied blindly).

Comment: Remove (& do not introduce) greetings, thanks, please, help me, excuse my English, signatures & other social noise. ("I'm a beginner" is reasonably left.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This is your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26789735).

It was rejected by the author of the question using one of the canned rejection reasons.

Regarding your edit itself, it was something of a mixed bag. While you slightly improved "not getting" and its associated run-on sentence, you introduced a spelling error for the word "empty", still didn't quite get the grammar right, and left in an arguably unnecessary "Please help me".

I do not know why the author decided to reject this, or why they chose the reason that they did. Given that they're a relatively new user, and thus unfamiliar with both the site's collaboratively-edited nature as well as the specific tools, it's possible that they rejected it in error. Or, perhaps they didn't like the way you had rephrased their post.

I likely would have rejected your edit as failing to substantially improve the post. [Edits are supposed to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Overall, I'm not sure this one did.

I've submitted an edit of my own that I believe addresses all of the problems and makes a more substantial improvement.

Comment: Thank you :) This will certainly help me to learn how to make better edits!

Comment: I know of some users who object to the very concept of other people being able to edit their posts, and will reject or rollback any and all edits regardless of quality. I know one guy who objected so strongly that he started *deleting* any posts of his that got edited. That's another possibility.

Comment: @F1Krazy If you see a pattern of behavior like that, it's a good time for a moderator flag. We can reach out to the user and explain how the site works, including the fact that it is collaboratively-edited.

Comment: Blame this issue on the fact, the author of the contribution, was forced to select a reason.  Since you failed to correct all the errors I would have rejected that proposal also